# Word for money given before a job is started

Tags: single-word-requests, american-english

Consider the scenario where a tutor is charging a student $100 for solving an assignment.

So the tutor takes $50 as a token before starting and rest $50 when it’s done.

A way to communicate this to the student is:

- You can transfer a **token** of $50 to me.
- I take **token** amount of $50 for this.

What are the alternatives ways of communicating the same?
I looked at the synonyms for *token* but couldn’t find an appropriate word.
Also, is the above use of word *token* correct or appropriate?

Comment: A part payment taken in advance is often called a _deposit_.

Comment: I would not use *token* here. A *token* is a small item representing something else (like a subway token representing a subway fare). You wouldn't normally speak of *$50* representing *$100.*

Comment: Alternatively, a token is a payment so small as to be negligible.  A person who gives a nickel to a charity drive has made a token donation.  Half the fee is not token.

Comment: While it's not directly related to your question, I feel ethically obliged to point out that the scenario you gave as an example (a tutor selling assignments to a student) is considered academic dishonesty in Western educational systems.

Comment: “Token” might be, imperfectly, considered a placeholder. So someone might pay a single dollar as a sign that they accept the exchange is a “pay for service” arrangement and not a gift or similar. Once “real” amounts of money are involved “token” will confuse the reader. $50 might be a token of intent if one were buying a car but not for a $100

Comment: There's a lot of good vocabulary to be found here but the title and contents and social situation all seem at odds with each other (or referring to different things). But 'token' doesn't seem appropriate for any of these situations (not AmE at least, maybe it's what is usually used in Indian English?)

Comment: The expression is UP FRONT
A typical way to express this situation is to say: "$50 up front, and the balance when the assignment is completed,"

Answer (score 24, accepted):

"Upfront" is the word I most commonly see used for this. You can use "upfront payment" if you're looking for a noun.

> Upfront: paid or obtained in advance
>
> [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/upfront)

As in:

> So the tutor asks for $50 upfront and the remaining $50 upon completion.

Or:

> So the tutor asks for an upfront payment of $50 and the remaining $50 to be paid upon completion.

This is a bit informal and may seem somewhat out of place in a contract or formal agreement, for example. In such cases I would probably expect to see something like "initial payment" or the details of when it should be paid written out without any single word or term used to describe it (e.g. "$50 to be paid prior to the commencement of the service").

Comment: I agree on the usage and examples, however _upfront_ is an adverb (1st example) / adjective (2nd), and OP seems to be looking for a noun.

Answer (score 56):

Such a payment made in advance of an anticipated complete transaction is often termed an *advance*

> Advance = money paid before something happens
>
> [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/advance)

The term has slightly less formal contractual overtones than the equally useful and very similar

> Deposit = to pay someone an amount of money when you make an agreement with that person to pay for or buy something, that either will be returned to you later, if the agreed arrangement is kept, or that forms part of the total payment
>
> [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/deposit)

Comment: I think "advance" usually carries some assumption of a nonguaranteed percentage of, say, sales that "deposit" does not. If your contract calls for a royalty of 1% of sales, and you get an advance of $1,000, then you won't seen any royalty payments until sales exceed $100,000.

Comment: I'm shocked deposit isn't the clear/obvious choice.

Answer (score 17):

Would you please transfer $50 to my account, as a **prepayment**?

or

**A 50% prepayment** is required for this service.

- [**prepay**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prepay) - "to pay for (something) before you receive or use it : to pay (something) before you are required to pay it."
- [**prepayment**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pre-payment) *also pre-payment* - "the act of paying for something before you receive it, or the amount of the payment"
  "Send your order with pre-payment by cheque".

Certain establishments (hotels, travel agencies, hospitals, car rentals) would require a **deposit**, which is slightly different from prepayment.

- [**deposit**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/deposit) A deposit is a sum of money which you pay when you start renting something. The money is returned to you if you do not damage what you have rented.

Comment: Instead of saying Would you please transfer $50 to my account, as a prepayment?  
Can i say can you transfer 50$  as prepayment ?  Is that correct english... 
or which one is better ? or polite

Comment: Also is the original word token does it sounds good ? or its kind of old and gross ??

Comment: @Rohitsharma "Token" is a perfectly good modern English word, but it means the wrong thing. All the relevant meanings refer to a physical object, not to a money payment.

Comment: @Rohitsharma "a token amount" in your OP usually means a *total* payment that is much lower than the true value of an object. It does not mean the *first part* of a bigger payment. For example you might sell an old object to somebody for a "token amount" of $100, because you didn't realize it was rare and valuable and really worth $100,000.

Comment: "Deposit" doesn't necessarily refer to money that is returned to you. It's quite often money that is used to hold a reservation, and then applied to the rental.

Answer (score 8):

When an author is writing a book, she or he may receive an

### Advance

> When a publisher is interested in acquiring a book manuscript, it usually offers the writer an advance against royalties, or *advance* for short.

> An advance is a signing bonus that’s negotiated and paid to the author before the book is published.

(Source: Writer's Digest -- [How Book Advances Work - A Simple Explanation for Writers](https://www.writersdigest.com/finances/how-book-advances-work-a-simple-explanation-for-writers))

Answer (score 7):

While not a single word, the term is regularly used as one:

- **[down payment](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/down%20payment)** - "a part of the full price paid at the time of purchase or delivery with the balance to be paid later".

Comment: This typically refers to something bought using a loan.

Answer (score 3):

*Advance* and *deposit*, which appear in previously posted answers, are probably the best general-purpose terms for such payments, but some professionals, particularly lawyers, prefer to refer to them by the term ***retainer***. A retainer can be either a payment for having the professional on standby, with an understanding that specific services will be paid for later, as they are rendered (a 'true retainer'), or a deposit for future services, from which the fees will be deducted as the services are rendered.

Comment: The word "retainer" is frequently used in conjunction with tutoring services. This is probably the best word in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

There are also the words "earnest" (no connection with other words so spelled) and "pledge". Maybe I would use "earnest" in this case, although these words are oftener used for a longer joint undertaking than an hour or twain of tutoring.

There is another case of early payment, in case of, say, a carpenter or plumber or such hired for a job, who also buys the material for it. For this, though, I would use the aforesaid expression "up front" and call it an up-front payment, payment up front for up-front costs.

Comment: usually earnest is combined with another word, such as "earnest money" or "earnest payment"

Answer (score -3):

A fixed or contingent payment above the regular salary is also called a **bonus**.  Although I wouldn’t normally use this term for a tutor, an extra incentive paid to a new employee is a [signing bonus](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/s/signing-bonus.asp).

It’s not clear from the question whether this is an extra one-time payment on top of the regular hourly fee, which would be a “bonus,” or a $50 advance on their regular salary, paid up front.  The latter would not be called a “bonus.”

Because some commenters claim that it sounds odd to them to say a tutor gets a bonus, I’ll give a few of many examples I found in a quick search.  Here’s a tutoring company [that offers new tutors a “$10 bonus”](https://www.rurututor.com/) for signing up.  Here’s a posting for a company calles [Tutor Time Childcare](https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/view/teacher-%242-000-sign-on-bonus%21-at-tutor-time-childcare-2309592553) that offers a “$2,000 sign-on bonus.” Here’s [a tutoring company that says “our compensation is performance/bonus based.”](https://www.indeed.com/cmp/Itutorgroup-1/faq)

Comment: It would be quite strange to pay a "bonus" to anyone who isn't an employee, I think.

Comment: A quick web search shows many examples of independent contractors getting a “bonus.” Sometimes even a “starting bonus.”

Comment: In any event, what is described here is not a bonus.

Comment: @Casey Native speakers do in fact describe it as a bonus.

Comment: I think Davislor is looking at the description in the title and not in the body of the question.  A signing bonus is certainly a commonly used term. However, the title is misleading and signing bonus is not at all what the OP us asking about.  It is asking about an upfront or advance payment.  And bonus does not work for that.

Comment: I am a native English speaker.  I would find it very strange if a tutor told me that I was to pay them a "bonus" before any service was rendered.

Comment: @Casey I posted a few examples (of many) of native speakers in the US referring to this as a “bonus.”

Comment: @Davislor those links are describing payments to tutors from a tutoring company employer. The customer is not making these payments, the tutoring company is. OP describes a direct payment from a customer to a tutor, not the same relationship.

Comment: @barbecue That’s just an artifact of big companies having a higher ranking in the search engine when I collected three hits off the first page. There are plenty of examples of private tutors saying things such as (from Britain) “Though it would be nice to receive a commission for every student who gained a distinction in a performance exam, and a yearly bonus that took into account your contribution towards the growth in the transferable skills of your students wouldn't go amiss either.”

Comment: Bottom line: a bonus is an extra payment. OP is talking about a split payment “half now, half on completion”. Neither of those payments is a bonus.

Comment: @Jim It’s not clear from the context. If that’s “$10/hour for five hours, plus a one-time payment of $50,’ the extra payment is a starting bonus. If it’s $10/hour for ten hours, with $50 up front and the next payment after hour six, it’s something else, like an advance.

Comment: The relevant pieces for me are: “charging $100 for solving an assigment” I infer from that that this a charge for the whole job, not a by the hour rate.  The tutor takes some (half) before starting and the ***rest*** when it’s done.  This means the payments are both parts of the full agreed-upon amount.

Comment: @davislor, In the links you provided, the wording is clearly describing an employer-employee relationship between a tutoring company and the tutors they hire. It's not describing a customer paying money to a tutor or tutoring company. The other example you provided mentions a yearly bonus, but again, that's not what the OP asked about. The question is asking about an initial payment from the customer to the tutor which retains the services of the tutor, and is applied to the final bill..

Comment: @barbecue I’ve got to assume there’s some kind of regional difference in our dialects, because it genuinely surprises me that you haven’t ever heard of a tutor getting a starting bonus. For example, doing the web search again quickly turned up a job-posting site in Bed-Stuy advertising “Part Time Tutors (Earn a Starting Bonus).” The first examples I posted were only for big companies because those were ranked higher in the search.

Comment: A fair summary of the comments so far: “starting bonus” is in common use, but many people don’t consider it correct, which is a valid reason to avoid it.

Comment: @Davisor again, "Part Time Tutors (Earn a Starting Bonus)" is something a company is paying to employees it hires, not something a customer is paying. That's the only issue with your answer, it doesn't address the specific case of an individual customer paying an individual tutor.

Comment: No. I did, in fact, already post at least one example of a private tutor writing about getting a  “bonus,” and you accepted that private tutors can get bonuses, but said this bonus  wasn’t a *starting* bonus. I also posted several examples of tutors getting a starting-or sign-on “bonus,” and you accepted that tutors can get a starting bonus, that that these tutors were employees, not private tutors. At this point, you are merely contending that *one specific type* of tutor cannot get this *one specific type* of bonus.