# Which is appropriate to use "budget for" or "willing to pay"

Tags: meaning, word-usage, sentence, sentence-meaning

Someone wants me to help him on assignment etc. Is it correct to ask

1. Whats your budget for this?
2. How much you are willing to pay for this?
3. Will 100$ work for you ? (Here I am directly giving the price whereas in the above two I am trying to get some Idea from him)

Any alternative better way?
It sounds more of a negotiating thing

Comment: Your question unfortunately sounds a bit like contract cheating. Might be better to say "Someone wants me to produce a <website/cake/Christmas dinner> and I want to know how much to charge for it". You want to charge appropriately, so might be better to work out how much work it is first.

Comment: Hmm. May be but I am into freelancing and many times unsure how much to charge. As there is no fixed market price in it

Comment: How long do you think it will take you to do the work? How much do you want to charge per hour? That'll give you a starting point.

Comment: I charge $100 an hour plus expenses.  When do we start?

Comment: What @Pam was reacting to was not that the question arose out of a context that had to do with freelance work, but that the work in question appears to be helping students cheat on educational assignments. If the word *assignment* in the question stands for something other than school assignments, that should be made clear. A similar comment was, incidentally, made to another [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/552301), asked by Ro**h**it sharma.

Comment: You're right @jsw29. The way both questions are worded, it sounds a lot like an assignment is being done for a fee. Not my place to judge, but the question could be improved by making it less specific to contract cheating. And in improving the question, the asker might do enough research to answer it alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. *What's your budget.* This works just fine.
2. I would go with: *How much do you want to invest in this project?*
3. Aside from your punctuation, you're okay here: *Will $100 work for you?*